# Sticky notification in windows not working

Tags: node-notifier

Does node-notifier support allowing the notification stay on the action center until dismissed by user? Timeout and wait attribute is currently not working

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @Brandon you just need to go to notification setting in windows and scroll down until you see SnoreToast and enable notifications there

Answer (score 0):

it's on depends on os. for mac its provides timeout and wait but for windows, it's not supported by windows.

Here are all notification options :

```
const NotificationCenter = require('node-notifier').NotificationCenter;

var notifier = new NotificationCenter({
  withFallback: false, // Use Growl Fallback if <= 10.8
  customPath: undefined // Relative/Absolute path to binary if you want to use your own fork of terminal-notifier
});

notifier.notify(
  {
    title: title,
    subtitle: subtitle,
    message: message,
    sound: false, // Case Sensitive string for location of sound file, or use one of macOS' native sounds (see below)
    icon: 'Terminal Icon', // Absolute Path to Triggering Icon
    contentImage: undefined, // Absolute Path to Attached Image (Content Image)
    open: undefined, // URL to open on Click
    wait: false, // Wait for User Action against Notification or times out. Same as timeout = 5 seconds

    // New in latest version. See `example/macInput.js` for usage
    timeout: 5, // Takes precedence over wait if both are defined.
    closeLabel: undefined, // String. Label for cancel button
    actions: undefined, // String | Array<String>. Action label or list of labels in case of dropdown
    dropdownLabel: undefined, // String. Label to be used if multiple actions
    reply: false // Boolean. If notification should take input. Value passed as third argument in callback and event emitter.
  },
  function (error, response, metadata) {
    console.log(response, metadata);
  }
);
```